# Can we start a windows service off a dll instead of an exe?

Tags: .net, windows-services, window

Just wondering, would it be possible to start a windows service off a .net 3.5 dll and not an exe ?

Is there any workaround which helps one do that ?

How can one specify an entry point in that case ?

Thanks,

KG

Comment: I think your question *"How can one specify an entry point in that case?"* pretty much sums it up here :)

Comment: :)..I heard about svchost.exe which could help one do this but I am not sure how reliable it is for usage in a production environment.

Comment: Perhaps a Windows Service expert will provide an answer to this question, I'm curious myself.  I've always used an EXE.

Comment: Hmm..Just read hosting services on svchost is a hard thing to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "oficial way" to run a .net dll as a windows service. It would require the svchost.exe to load the DLL and bind to the start/stop exports. However there MS do not provides documentation on such topic.

In [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx) the terms used are "service application" or "service executable", so no "dll way" either.

EDIT:

Just found this attempt to run a dll as a service (pain!): http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic11974.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had some issues downloading  the service exes into  the host due to antivirus blocking it. It looks like a dead-end since it blocks any exe download and dlls seem to get through.

Comment: I see, if you have control over the download process, maybe you could download the exe via http an encrypted string stream to by pass the AV (although the AV still could block the installation). A msi setup could be an option too...